# Creating a graph diagram of time stamp with VBA

Tags: vba, time

I am new to VBA and I have a small question I have to create a graph for a log data and it seems to be tricky. For example:

```
 Date and time            X   A    B    C    D  
2017-03-23_11-48-32.8   1000 500 26400 26400 80
2017-03-23_11-48-32.8   1000 400 26400 26400 75
2017-03-23_11-48-32.8   1000 700 26400 26400 70
2017-03-23_11-48-32.8   1000 800 26400 26400 72
2017-03-23_11-48-32.8   1000 900 26400 26400 68
2017-03-23_11-48-32.8   1000 300 26400 26400 55
```

Here the time has to be in the X axis and the other data  X,A,B,C,D in the Y axis.

The main question is how to I separate the time only from the date and time column and how to create the corresponding graph

Thanks for the help

Comment: In either vba or excel you want the LEFT function:  https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/left.php

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `Format` funtion to convert to a time, assuming that your 'Date and Time' is stored as a `date` the below is an example of how to extract a time from a date time:

```
Sub getTime()
    Dim d As Date
    d = Now
    Debug.Print Format(d, "hh:mm:ss")
End Sub
```

To make the graph, I would use the macro recorder, there is a question on that subject here:

[How do I create a stacked column chart purely through programming with excel vba?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3209764/how-do-i-create-a-stacked-column-chart-purely-through-programming-with-excel-vba)